# Show source code in TextView correctly indented and parsed

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to parse HTML code in a verbatim mode or something similar so that the source code fragments that eventually may appear (enclosed between **pre** and **code** HTML tags) can be displayed properly?

What I want to do is show source code in a user-friendly mode (easy to distinguish from the rest of the text, keep indentation, etc.), as Stack Overflow does :)

It seems that Html.fromHtml() supports only a [reduced subset](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) of HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I preparsed by myself the HTML code received, since Html.fromHtml does not support the `pre` and `code` tags, y replaced them with my custom format and pre-parsed the code inside those tags replacing "\n" with `<br/>` and " " with `&nbsp;`.

Then I send the results to Html.fromHtml, and the result is just fine:

```
public class HtmlParser {
    public static Spanned parse(String text) {
        if (text == null) return null;

        text = parseSourceCode(text);

        Spanned textSpanned = Html.fromHtml(text);
        return textSpanned;
    }

    private static String parseSourceCode(String text) {
        if (text.indexOf(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN) < 0) return text;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int begin;
        int end;
        int beginIndexToProcess = 0;

        while (text.indexOf(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN) >= 0) {
            begin = text.indexOf(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN);
            end = text.indexOf(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_END);

            String code = parseCodeSegment(text, begin, end);

            result.append(text.substring(beginIndexToProcess, begin));
            result.append(PARSED_PATTERN_BEGIN);
            result.append(code);
            result.append(PARSED_PATTERN_END);

            //replace in the original text to find the next appearance
            text = text.replaceFirst(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN, PARSED_PATTERN_BEGIN);
            text = text.replaceFirst(ORIGINAL_PATTERN_END, PARSED_PATTERN_END);

            //update the string index to process
            beginIndexToProcess = text.lastIndexOf(PARSED_PATTERN_END) + PARSED_PATTERN_END.length();
        }

        //add the rest of the string
        result.append(text.substring(beginIndexToProcess, text.length()));

        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String parseCodeSegment(String text, int begin, int end) {
        String code = text.substring(begin + ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN.length(), end);
        code = code.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        code = code.replace("\n","<br/>");
        return code;
    }

    private static final String ORIGINAL_PATTERN_BEGIN = "<pre><code>";
    private static final String ORIGINAL_PATTERN_END = "</code></pre>";

    private static final String PARSED_PATTERN_BEGIN = "<font color=\"#888888\"><tt>";
    private static final String PARSED_PATTERN_END = "</tt></font>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextView` will never succeed supporting all the html formating and styling you would want it to. Use [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead.

`TextView` is native and more lightweight, but exactly because of its lightweightedness it will not understand some of the directives you describe.

Comment: Well, I just need to print text as-is, keeping indentation, as a verbatim tag would do. I'll continue searching, I think that a WebView is too much complexity for what I want to get.

Comment: @LuisRodríguez but if it is only for identation, why text view would not do for you? I mean it supports both newlines and tabs.

Comment: Yes, in the end I pre-parsed myself the "pre" and "code" tags, using my own custom formatting and replacing "\n" with <br/> and whitespaces with "&nbsp;"; then, sending the results to Html.fromHtml. I'll post below my solution.

Comment: @LuisRodríguez but why do you insist on using `fromHtml` if you don't you would not need to convert twice - first to the tags and then have the method convert back again...

Comment: The content that I want to show in the view is full HTML text downloaded via JSON, so it's not a web page or URL content. This rich HTML code is not fully understood by `Html.fromHtml`, so I just need to help  it :-)

Comment: @LuisRodríguez my thought was rather that you eihter way do substitution... why don't you substitute in a way to turn the source to plain text, rather to simpler html and then still use `fromHtml`?

Comment: That's not in my side, I use a 3rd. party source of data :-), so I just get the data, parse it and show it.