# Code Formatting in TextView

Tags: android, formatting, textview

I am currently working on an offline algorithm displaying app. I want to show code using textview. I want to show code with color code how to do that?

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: You could try formatting the string with HTML but that would be kind of painful.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422791/show-source-code-in-textview-correctly-indented-and-parsed

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Spanned](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html):

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Red</font> and <font color='blue'>Blue</font>");
yourTextView.setText(text);
```

Comment: Yah I know this but how to find int only from code? like I have comments also in my code which also contains int so by this way int in comment will also have red color which I don't want.